# How to store relational data in mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

I want to store data related to address. I have lot of countries with states to each of them and in turn cities to each of them. In relational database like mysql I would store in the following way

```
CREATE TABLE countries (name VARCHAR(20), id int(20)...few more attributes);
CREATE TABLE states (name VARCHAR(20), id int(20), countryId int(20) ...few more attributes);
CREATE TABLE cities (name VARCHAR(20), id int(20), stateId int(20)...few more attributes);
```

I would always know the state while asking for city, country while asking for state. What is the idea way to store such data in mongodb. There is one more way I can think of in mongodb

```
var Country = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    states: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Testrun'
    }]
});
var State = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    cities: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Testrun'
    }]
});
var City = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    }

});
```

I feel that if I store the way we do in mysql, updating, creating or deleting would be much more easy.

Comment: "How to store relational data in MongoDB?" sounds just like "How to store a square peg in a round hole?". One will have to suffer some abuse to get hammered into form, either the peg or the hole. Which one do you want it to be?

Comment: MongoDB is not a relational database. If you want to store your countries, states, and cities like you do in MySQL, then use MySQL. In mongo you can have it two ways: 1) Store the three tables as three separate collections, or 2) Nest the cities under the states which are nested under the countries (as your example shows). As to which way is better entirely depends on your use case.